# Joining two data sets with timestamps that are slightly off

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, one with transactions and one that reflects an audit done on each of these transactions before they were allowed process.  I'd like to join the audit results to each transaction.  Unfortunately, due to a system error, the `TransID` sometimes gets duplicated and thus does not always uniquely identify the transaction event.  What DOES uniquely identify the event is the `TransID + TransTimestamp`.  The row in the auditor's data that is uniquely associated with this transaction is the one with the same `TransID` and an `AuditTimestamp` that's the most recent timestamp that comes before the `TransTimestamp`.  The code I've tried below causes SQL developer to run perpetually:

```
SELECT Trans.TransID, Audit.AuditTimestamp  
FROM Trans
LEFT JOIN Audit ON Trans.TransID = Audit.TransID  
WHERE Trans.TransTimestamp >= (SELECT MAX(Audit.AuditTimestamp)  
                          FROM Audit
                          WHERE Trans.TransID = Audit.AuditID);
```

Comment: Please show some sample data.  How big are these tables?  Are they indexed properly?

Comment: Should you be using `Audit.TransID` instead of `Audit.AuditID` in the correlated subquery in your WHERE clause?   Also, because the correlated subquery will be evaluated for every row in the `Trans` table, you might get better performance if you apply additional criteria, such as `Audit.Timestamp < Trans.Timestamp`.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. Don't you need to join the two tables and to retrieve some information from the join? Selecting only the TransID and the AuditTimestamp is pretty pointless. Then: Aren't you looking to match three possible transactions (say), all with the same TransID in both tables, but with different timestamps, which should distinguish three truly different transactions, except that the timestamps aren't exactly equal? Nothing along those lines is present in your query.

Comment: Then: you are doing a left join, which means some transactions may not have been audited? That's a problem! What if you had three different transactions, but due to your flawed system they all got the same TransID... then you have only two rows in the Audit table? Matching rows between the two tables based on most recent AuditTimestamp that comes before the TransTimestamp may match the wrong rows, due to the missing Audit row. You should have an additional rule that the difference between timestamps is no more than a set (short) time interval.

Comment: And - other than the point I made in the previous Comment - it is not clear why you need "most recent", etc. - if all transactions were audited, and Audit Timestamp was in the same order as Trans Timestamp, that would be the only info needed to match the right transaction with the right audit row. Finally: Are you going to fix the system that assigns non-unique TransID's? If not, why not?

Comment: I don't get it. There is a transaction table `trans`, but `transid` is not its primary key and so you have duplicates? Why is that? And a transaction has a date and the audits upon it occur *before* that date, not after?

Answer (score 0):

If a core piece of information such a transid is being duplicated then it is a "very messy business" and no amount of workarounds will properly overcome this.

To attempt this query I think you need to divide the transactions into those which have problems and those which don't and below I have used COUNT() OVER() to establish if a transaction has been duplicated or not. From there we can use a correlated subquery to locate a "probable  match" for those transactions that need this approach. The probable match needs to have a timestamp >= the transaction but less than some allowed timeframe e.g. 1 second.

From there we join the good with the bad to arrive at (hopefully) something reasonable. But although it may appear reasonable it isn't guaranteed to be, you do need to fix the source problem.

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT
          trans.*
        , COUNT() over(partition by Trans.TransID) tran_count
    FROM Trans
    )
, A2 AS (
    SELECT 
           T.TransID
         , SELECT MIN(Audit.AuditTimestamp) FROM Audit
            WHERE T.TransID = Audit.TransID 
            AND Audit.AuditTimestamp > T.TransTimestamp
            AND Audit.AuditTimestamp < (T.TransTimestamp + interval '1' second) /* change to suit */
            AS ProbableMatch
    FROM T
    WHERE T.tran_count > 1
    )
SELECT 
       T.TransID
     , T.trans_count
     , COALESECE(A1.AuditTimestamp, A2.ProbableMatch) AS AuditTimestamp
     , COALESECE(A1.ID, A3.ID) AS SourceAuditID
FROM T
LEFT JOIN Audit A1 ON T.TransID = A1.TransID AND T.tran_count = 1
LEFT JOIN A2 ON T.TransID = A2.TransID
LEFT JOIN Audit A3 ON A2.TransID = A3.TransID AND A2.AuditTimestamp = A3.AuditTimestamp
```